# JasperReports PdfServlet to save report in PDF - how can I set the filename for the browser to prompt the user?

Tags: jsf, jasper-reports

Stack: **JSF** + **PrimeFaces** on **JBoss AS** with **JasperReports**

I have been using a pattern of exporting in PDF format using JasperReports with a three steps process:

[1] obtain the compiled Jasper report from a path in the **war**

[2] place the **JasperPrint** object on the session

[3] redirect to the URL of the **PdfServlet**

So when the user from the GUI clicks on a **p:commandButton** a backing-bean's method is called that goes through [1], [2] and [3] as in the following example code:

**xhtml file:**

```
<p:commandButton ajax="false" action="#{indexController.exportPDF}" value="Export PDF"/>
```

**backing bean code:**

```
private void putPrintObjectInSession() throws JRException {
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ServletContext context = (ServletContext) externalContext.getContext();
    String reportFileName = context.getRealPath("/reports/PrimeNumbersReport.jasper");
    File reportFile = new File(reportFileName);
    if (!reportFile.exists())
        throw new JRRuntimeException(".jasper file not found in the war.");
    Map parameters = new HashMap();
    parameters.put("ReportTitle", "2nd Prime Numbers Report");
    parameters.put("BaseDir", reportFile.getParentFile());
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = 
            JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                      reportFileName, 
                      parameters, 
                      getSQLConnection()
                    );
    ((HttpSession) externalContext.getSession(false)).setAttribute(BaseHttpServlet.DEFAULT_JASPER_PRINT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, jasperPrint);
}

public String exportPDF() throws IOException, JRException {
    putPrintObjectInSession();
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();  
    externalContext.redirect("servlets/pdf");
    return null;
}
```

I have two questions:

[i] do you see any obvious code smells or limitations with this approach?

[ii] with the example code above both Chrome and Conkeror can save the report but the default filename they present to the user for saving the file is simply "pdf". How can I configure that to a meaningful name (e.g. "report-2012-08-23c.pdf") ?

Comment: I'm working with JSF and JasperReports too. In my case, we don't save anything in session, we generate the PDF (or Excel or another format) from the JasperReport and then download the content to the user client (by writing the file content on the response). This approach works well for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to your concrete problem with the "Save as" filename, it defaults to the last path in the request URL (which is in case of `/servlets/pdf` indeed just `pdf`), unless otherwise specified in `Content-Disposition` header.

The problem is not directly caused by your JSF code (although it is at its own kind of odd, but that's a different problem/question), but more in the servlet which is been mapped on `/servlets/pdf`. To set the desired "Save as" filename, you need to add the following line before writing any byte to the response:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
```

You can if necessary replace `attachment` by `inline` if you want to display it by default inline.

The Internet Explorer browser, however, ignores this value and sticks to using the last path in the request URL. So to cover that browser as well, you'd need to include the desired filename in the request URL yourself and change the servlet mapping.

E.g.

```
String filename = "report-2012-08-23c.pdf";
externalContext.redirect("servlets/pdf/" + filename);
```

with

```
@WebServlet("/servlets/pdf/*") // instead of @WebServlet("/servlets/pdf")
```

With this URL pattern, the filename is inside the servlet available by

```
String filename = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
```